# Passing this to a method of a class variable of this

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have the following situation in my code and don't know if it reveals some wrong design.

```
class A
{
public:
   ...
   void estimateParameters(const std::vector<double> &data);
private:
   B m_algorithm;
   int m_parameter1;
   int m_parameter2;
};

void A::estimateParameters(const sdt::vector<double> &data)
{
   m_algorithm.estimate(this, data);  // And then m_parameter1 and m_parameter2 are filled
}
```

The implementation of `estimateParameters` calls the `estimate` method of `B`, which receives as parameter a pointer to `this`. It sounds a little bit strange to me and seems redundant. I am employing this scheme to encapsulate the parameter estimation of `A` without enforcing the user to manually create an instance of `B` in his code and then pass `A`. It is a way to make transparent the parameter estimation to the user.

It is common this type of scheme? Do you think it is the best way to do this? Any alternative less redundant or clearer?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't it be `m_algorithm.estimate(this, data);` instead of `B.m_algorithm`?

Comment: If anything, pass `*this` by reference.

Comment: yes sorry, I have changed it

Comment: You may also group your parameters, and pass than only the parameters to  `m_algorithm`.

Answer (score 1):

To make this cleaner I'd pass the parameters as a structure. There's no need for Class B to know everything about Class A.

**Example Code**

```
// Struct that class B can use without having to 'know' about class A
struct EstimateParameters
{
    int m_parameter1;
    int m_parameter2;
};

class B
{
public:
    void estimate(const EstimateParameters& estimateParams, const std::vector<double> &data)
    {
        /*  Use estimate params to act on data. 
            We don't care about the whole of class A, only performing estimates */
    }
};

// Class A now composed of EstimateParameters.
class A
{
public:
    void estimateParameters(const std::vector<double> &data);
private:
    EstimateParameters m_estimateParams;
    B m_algorithm;
};

// Passing only the private structure of params, not details of the whole of class A.
void A::estimateParameters(const std::vector<double> &data)
{
    m_algorithm.estimate(m_estimateParams, data);  
}
```

**Edited this answer based on useful comments, thanks guys!**

Comment: Point 1. is clear. Point 2. remains a little bit difficult to me to understand. Can you clarify it please? Thank you.

Comment: Will upload an example soon

Comment: @Javier Added it for point 2 only, will try to include point 1 soon

Comment: Hi @Javier I've updated the example to include both points. B now takes an interface reference during construction that A implements. Now you can use that reference during estimates in B. B never needs to know everything about A, only that it provides parameters to estimates.

Comment: No No, sorry. I just understood

Comment: Thank you, very much. I have voted your answer but I don't have badges to be useful. Sorry.

Comment: No problems @Javier hope you find it useful :-)

Comment: Do you think inheritance (instead of composition) is a good way to provide a set of parameters?

Comment: @moooeeeep That's a good question! I was more interested in providing a way to decouple class A from B. I'm sure there's plenty more you could do.

Comment: Doesn't it violate the ["prefer composition over inheritance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle?

Comment: Updated my answer to take into account your useful comments. Many thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Your design reminds me of the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), which makes sense to me in this example.

One problem here is that `B` depends on `A`. You could remove this dependency by passing the parameters by reference (instead of the this-pointer).

```
m_algorithm.estimate(m_parameter1, m_parameter2, data);
```

Also, it might make sense to define a Parameters class (or struct).

```
struct Parameters {
    int m_parameter1;
    int m_parameter2;
}

class A {
public:
    void estimateParameters(const std::vector<double>& data);
private:
    B m_algorithm;
    Parameters m_parameters;
};

void A::estimateParameters(const std::vector<double>& data) {
    m_algorithm.estimate(m_parameters, data);
}

void B::estimate(Parameters& parameters, const std::vector<double>& data) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, but in the real case there are not only two parameters, but a lot of stuff. Hence, your recommendation of the Parameters class I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is a good way of passing pointer to object. It is not redundant.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13585539)

Comment: @BWA this is neither critic nor request. It is an answer to question asked at the end of the post.

Comment: But in this form it is comment.

Comment: Sometimes the answer to a question is just "yes" or "no". Reviewers have a bad habit of marking things for deletion based on the length of the content alone. This is an answer - if you don't like it then downvote. IMHO it shouldn't be a candidate for deletion.

Comment: The answer to a question can be Yes or No, I thoroughly agree. Though is it useful without at-least a small explanation of why? References always help too.